Multiple eCharts graphs in one page and data mapping / [ECharts] `setOption` should not be called during main process
I'm trying to put multiple charts of eCharts in one page of only one type with series like (type: 'line') but datas should be formatted according to different parameters for each graph.
For a single graph it is quite simple using:
option = {
    dataset: {
        source: datamapping(data),
    },
    //...
}

where datamapping it's a function like
function datamapping(data){
   var parameter_used_for_data_mapping = 'serverSideAssignmentVariable'; //this is important
   data.map(item => [ otherFunctionForMapping(item[0], parameter_used_for_data_mapping) ,item[1] ]); // mapping time: (uses parameter_used_for_data_mapping for xAxis)
   return data;
}

But when I have multiple graphs I can't use the same function datamapping(data) because each graph has a different parameter var parameter_used_for_data_mapping to map data.
I would get a javascript error telling me that there are multiple functions with the same name if I create one for each graph (server side). Also option wouldn't know which function it was referencing since they would all have the same name.

So you need a callback function like:
option = {
    dataset: {
        source: (data) => {
           var parameter_used_for_data_mapping = 'serverSideAssignmentVariable';
           //here inside the datamap
           return data;
        },
    },
    //...
}

But if I do something like this I got a big red error in console that has been bothering my eyes for hours and hours
[ECharts] `setOption` should not be called during main process.

Now the real question:
How can you map data for multiple charts differently in such a condition?

dataset.source can't be a function; if you want to use a function there, you have to call that function before you assign it to source, as you did in your first example; in the last code piece, doesn't something like source: ((data) => {......})(data) work? Otherwise, you should explain more what your constraints are, for instance why don't you set different function names on the server, like datamapping_0, datamapping_1, etc. You should also consider having different option objects also (object_0, object_1, etc.)

@ kikon About ((data) => {......})(data) I have never seen such a type of javascript callback function. Can you explain what kind of function it is and what it means to pass data as a parameter to the callback function and then use the parentheses at the end again with data please? What construct is it and why this redundancy? Anyway datamapping had to be inside option [that on the contrary as object is multiple (one for chart)]. However, as you wrote, your code works very well.

To summarize the currently working structure is when you have multiple objects option created server-side, datamapping is completely eliminated (to avoid creating millions of functions) and the data mapping is done via callback function directly in options as you wrote in your code in the comment. If you can explain why you include the callback in round brackets and pass data in other round brackets I would be grateful.

I actually used your first example where you havesource: datamapping(data); the version I proposed is equivalent, but instead of using the function name (datamapping) you may put the whole function expression inside parenthesis. This way you don't need to assign a name to the function. In the second example you use a function for source, but the problem is that you don't call that function as in the first case, so just put it in parenthesis and add the arguments to call it before assigning the result to source.

It's the second case that interests me. I put aside the first example. I'm already using your second example with the round brackets (the one without the datamapping function: anonymous callback function for the source attribute). Could you please link something that makes me understand what structure this is. Why data twice? I didn't understand anything . It's like a function in a function?!

In source: ((data) => { .....})(data), the first and the last data don't need to be the same name.  You could have ((data) => { .....})(myData); I used data again as it seemed to be the name you assigned that global variable (I gathered that it was your choice to use data both for the formal argument of the function and the global variable). The expression ((data) => { .....}) evaluates to the function that you previously assigned to a variable. The need for parentheses is the same as in (1+2)*3, without parenthesis it would  try to link {...}(data) before the => operator.

So I still don't understand why source: ((data) => { .....})(data) works and source: (data) => { .....} doesn't. Considering that the outer function does nothing except pass data to the inner function. Anyway TNX.  If u have some time look @ this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79004206/how-to-know-what-graph-are-you-referring-with-multiple-echarts-graphs-in-one-pag
